# Number of four-digit numbers which are divisible by $4$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

The question is to find out the number of four-digit numbers  which are divisible by $4$.

The number of all four-digit numbers is $$9\times10\times10\times10=9000$$
I am not sure about the divisibility rule for $4$ and how to use it here. Something we can note is that the number should be even. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @lonestudent, I didn't get that. What is $4k+4$? What is $k$?

Comment: Take $1000+4k, k≥0, k \in\mathbb Z$ where $$4k+1000<9999$$

Comment: My question still holds.

Comment: then you can find $\max k$. And $k+1$ is the answer.

Comment: @lonestudent,  $k+1$ because $1000+4\times0=1000$ ($k=0$) which is also divisible by $4$, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You know that every fourth number is divisible by four. We have a total of $9000$ 4-digit numbers. As $1000$ is divisible by four we can conclude that exactly
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{9000}{4} \right\rfloor = 2250
$$
4-digit numbers are divisible by four. You don't even need any rules for a number being divisible by four.

This fact can be used for divisibility by any other number $n$ as well.

Edit: In general ceiling should be used if under the first $n-1$ numbers there exist a number divisible by $n$, otherwise flooring is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am not sure I see it, though. Every fourth number is divisible by four, OK. But why by dividing $9000\over 4$ we get the number of 4-digit numbers divisible by four? Are we including the first number $1000$ for example?

Comment: Yeah we do. We only have to be careful if the amount of consecutive numbers is not divisible by four ($9000$ luckily is divisible by four). You can imagine this by starting with just $4$ consecutive numbers. You will always find one of them divisible by four. If you instead look at only $3$ consecutive numbers, you can get unlucky and find $0$ numbers. That's why flooring is used.

Comment: You can use the pigeon-hole principle: There are four pots representing the four values $0,1,2,3$ that can remain after dividing by four. As these remainders are equally distributed one can never have 2 numbers more in one pot than in the other (at max. $1$). But as we have $9000$ numbers to put in those pots, we have to divide them evenly across those four pots

Comment: Okay, but should we look at $[1000,1001,1002,1003]$, for example, or should we start with the previous number which is divisible by four?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is?

Comment: Isn't it $\left\lceil\frac{9000}{4}\right\rceil$ instead? Since the list of 9000 four-digit numbers starts with a number divisible by 4. The result is the same, but say we didn't want to include 9999 for some arbitrary reason and thus had 8999 numbers in our list.

Comment: In that case it doesn't matter as $\lfloor \frac{9000}{4}\rfloor = \lceil \frac{9000}{4}\rceil = 2250$. However in general you are correct and if we would had a list of only $8999$ numbers, we should use ceiling as the first number is divisible by $4$. I add this to my answer

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more general approach uses, rather than the size of the interval you're looking at, specifically the *endpoints*. First of all, note that in the range $[1\ldots n]$, exactly $\lfloor\frac n4\rfloor$ numbers are divisible by 4. (Write out the values for small $n$ and you should see how the pattern arises). More generally, we could say that for any divisor $d$, exactly $\lfloor\frac nd\rfloor$ of the numbers in the range $[1\ldots n]$ are divisible by $d$.

Now, we can think about the set of four-digit numbers this way: it's exactly the set of numbers from $1$ to $9999$ *minus* the set of numbers from $1$ to $999$. More generally, the set of numbers in the range $[a\ldots b]$ (assuming $a\leq b$ here) is the difference between the set of numbers in the range $[1\ldots b]$ and the set in the range $[1\ldots (a-1)]$. So if we take the number of divisible-by-4 numbers in the range $[1\ldots 9999]$ and subtract the number in the range $[1\ldots 999]$, we'll get exactly the number in the range $[1000\ldots 9999]$: $\lfloor\frac{9999}4\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{999}4\rfloor$ $= 2499-249$ $=2250$.